# Ways to wait for elements to load when adding eventlisteners

Tags: javascript, html

I'm playing around with parcel before I used liveserver in vscode and I rarely ran into this problem. I'm trying to add a eventlistener to a inputform. DOM isn't finding the element no matter what I do. I've tried to put a if statement checking if the element exist before putting a listener but it doesn't change anything. I never had this problem using liveserver, do i have to write a asynchronous function and wait for the page to load? I tried putting defer inside the script tag aswell. Is parcel slower than liveserver somehow?

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
if(input1)
{
    console.log("The input exists");
    input1.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        console.log("heey");
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/scss/main.scss">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputlg">input</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text" id="input1">
            <label for="inputlg">output</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text">
        </div>

    </form>
    <script type="module" src="./assets/js/main.js" ></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` but if you want to beat that, you can use `MutationObserver` to watch the DOM as the page is still loading, but that's an _advanced_ use-case...

Comment: You can't have two id attributes on the same tag. Leave only one here <input type="text" id="input1"> and id should be unique for all elements in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Your input has two ids. That's invalid, and `getElementById` doesn't see the second one.

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
console.log(input1); // null

const inputlg = document.getElementById('inputlg');
console.log(inputlg); // input#inputlg.form-control.input-lg
```

```html
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text" id="input1">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways.

1. (best) `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // code here })`
2. `document.onreadystatechange = () => { if (document.readystate == "complete") { // code here } }`

Also, it is a requirement that there is only 1 element assigned to each ID. In your code, you have 2 elements with ID "inputlg", which is not allowed. Get rid of those and it should work. You also have an element which you are trying to have 2 IDs on, which also does not work.

The code above is just to make sure that the document is fully loaded, and prevents errors.